# Как добавить класс routerLink по которому я перешел

Tags: маршрутизация, события, angular5, angular

задумка такая что когда я перехожу по ссылке `<nav  routerLink="" class="pages__link">` 
мне нужно добавить *класс* `.active{color: red}` что говорит пользователю что он находиться на этой странице и когда он переходит на другую страницу то этот *класс* удаляется с этой и присваивается к другой итд...

на *jquery* это бы выглядело так

```
$('.el').on('click', function() {
   $('.el').css({ color: 'black' })
   $(this).css({ color: 'red' })
})
```

но хотелось бы не просто присвоить класс к ссылке а именно после того как *роутер* выполнил успешно ***NavigationEnd*** то есть как *колбек* на успешный event , и присвоить класс именно той ссылке `*( routerLink )*` по которой перешел пользователь ?

**app.component.html**

```
<header class="df jcc aic">
  <nav class="page df jcc aic">
      <nav  routerLink="" class="pages__link">{{ 'home' | uppercase }}</nav>
      <nav  routerLink="about" class="pages__link">{{ 'about' | uppercase }}</nav>
      <nav  routerLink="galery" class="pages__link">{{ 'galery' | uppercase }}</nav>
  </nav>
</header>
 <div class="container" [@fadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
   <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'galery', component: GaleryComponent }
];
```

Comment: Вы курили [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<header class="df jcc aic">
  <nav class="page df jcc aic">
    <nav routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="" class="pages__link">{{ 'home' | uppercase }}</nav>
    <nav routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="about" class="pages__link">{{ 'about' | uppercase }}</nav>
    <nav routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="galery" class="pages__link">{{ 'galery' | uppercase }}</nav>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="container" [@fadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```